# Make a function to connect in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my code:

```
    NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *dataReply;
NSString *stringReply;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: URLGOESHERE]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
stringReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I want to put that in a function soo that i can call it from all my other buttons but i can set the

```
URLWithString: URLGOESHERE]];
```

how would i do this and how would i call it ?

Thanks

Mason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the explanation below for why this is a **bad** idea.

```
- (NSString *)sendRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *dataReply;
    NSString *stringReply;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
    dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    stringReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [stringReply autorelease];
}
```

Then

```
NSString *response = [self sendRequestWithURLString:@"....."];
```

---

So, take note, if you call this from a button, it will block the main thread until it finishes, which is bad. You need to look into asynchronous requests, or at the very least use dispatch_async.

Comment: asynchronous ? how would i do that ?

Comment: NSURLConnection has asynchronous methods.